# Flexslider with more than 42+ images

Tags: jquery, flexslider

Am applying flexslider for dynamic added images to slide one by one in my application. Slider is working as expected as upto 42 images, but after 43 image, the slider is not working as expected as.

Here is my JS code :-

```
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
            selector: ".slides > li",
            animation: "slide",
            direction: "horizontal",
            animationLoop: false,
            startAt: 0,
            slideshow: false,
            controlNav: false,
            directionNav: true,
            prevText: "Previous",
            nextText: "Next", 
            itemWidth: 110,
            itemMargin: 20,
            move:1,
            minItems: 1000,
            maxItems: 1000,
            before: function(slider){
                $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide + 1);
            },
            start: function(slider){
                $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide + 1);
                $('.total-slides').text(slider.count);
                $('#sliderNext').on('click', function(e){
                    $('.flex-next').trigger('click');
                    slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("next"));
                });
                $('#sliderPrev').on('click', function(e){
                    $('.flex-prev').trigger('click');
                    slider.flexAnimate(slider.getTarget("prev"));
                });
            },
            after: function(slider){
                $('.current-slide').text(slider.currentSlide + 1);
            },
            end: function(slider){                  
                slider.flexAnimate(0);
            }
        });
```

When i cross check with inspect element in FF, i observed that the plugin is not applied for list image items. When i deleted one image it is applying and it is working as expected. Please help me out from this issue.

Comment: 43 images ? seriously ? use ajax

Comment: How, from where are you loading the images? Do you have some errors when you load 43 images?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Am manipulating the DOM and am not getting any errors after loading 43 images. Okay i will try with Ajax.